# trigger Ajax xmlhttp function when submitting form

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to trigger an ajax call/object instantiation when i submit a form. Can i do this vie the `action=""` field?

```
<FORM id="form" METHOD="GET" ACTION="">
<b> Enter argument: </b>
<input size="40" name="q" id="q" value="">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" id="q" VALUE="Submit">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset">
</FORM>
```

in the same same file i have a function:

```
function xmlhttpPost(){
...
request = new ajaxRequest()
...
request.open("GET","xmlget.php?url=" + $search + nocache, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onclick handler to the submit button, like so:

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" id="q" VALUE="Submit" onclick="someJavaScript()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `form`'s `onsubmit` event.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to the form's submit event, and then make your ajax request in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use onsubmit="function();" Also once you get this working you will also have to prevent the form from submitting according to the "action" jQuery provides event.preventDefault(); which works the best from what I've seen.